# bootstrap-datepicker to show in full screen

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using the plugin: https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker

JSFiddle DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/j3b089gr/

I'm showcasing the calendar with the HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5">first column</div>
  <div class="col-7">
    <input class="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
  </div>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

I would like to show the calendar in full screen but I'm unable to do this. It only shows in the `col-7` area. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using data-api to generate datepicker in your fiddle, so the js code is not being execute.
(
[doc about data api](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#data-api)

> For most datepickers, simply set data-provide="datepicker" on the element you want to initialize, and **it will be intialized lazily**, in true bootstrap fashion.
>   )

try to generate datepicker using js and add  'container' option, then you can write some custom style to make it full screen:

```js
var widthPerDay = window.innerWidth / 7; 
var heightPerDay = window.innerHeight / 6;

$('.datepicker').datepicker({container:'body',orientation:'auto bottom'}).on('show',function(){ 
$('.dropdown-menu').addClass('overlay'); // to position the datepicker, or just do it here
 $('.datepicker td').css( {"width":widthPerDay,"height":heightPerDay } ); // change the size of day elements to make the datepicker table resize.
  $('.datepicker th').css( {"width":widthPerDay,"height":heightPerDay } );
 
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu.overlay{
  left:0 !important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">First Column</div>
    <div class="col-7">
        <input class="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---